# Partitions using same registry and windows files

Tags: windows-xp

Using Partition Magic and have 3 different Partitions.

For some odd reason 2 of these partitions are sharing registry and windows files.

They are both xp 32 bit.

They are not supposed to share same files or Registry.

Anyway to fix this ?

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking. What are the three partitions? What do you mean by "sharing registry and Windows files"?

Comment: Basically 3 partitions, so a chunk of space allocated for each. Basically a HDD of 240 gb is split to 3 disk with 80 gb. These parititons are hidden from each other. Each having their own OS. So you can hide the ones you do not use and boot to a different one.

Comment: Yes, I know what partitions are, but how are they sharing the same registry and Windows files? You said that all three have an OS already installed on them; are they all Windows? How did you set them up? Did you *copy* the Windows installation to all three or did you *install* Windows on each *after* making the partitions?

Comment: I am sad to say this but I do not know and nor does the person with issue.

Comment: Since you have no idea how this was set up, I'm voting to close.

Comment: @RezaM., so how did the partitions get made? Where did the copies of Windows come from? `o.O`

Comment: Dunno, I am just a helping hand to that fellow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windows was installed *after* the partitions were made, then they should work fine.

However, from your description, it sounds more like Windows was installed on the single partition which was then shrunk and copied to the two new partitions.

In that case, all three copies of Windows will be set to use `C:` and therefore all of them are using the same copy of the registry and Windows files. What you need to do is to re-install Windows on the other two partitions, specifying the other drive letters—e.g., `D:` and `E:`. (Theoretically you *could* edit the registry and files of the other two copies to replace all occurrences of `C:`, but that would be ***much*** more work than just re-installing, and even then, not guaranteed to work.)

As a side note, this is a problem because you are using Windows XP. With Vista and higher, Windows *always* uses `C:` as the system drive, even if it is not the first partition. That is why if you dual-boot XP and 7, both copies will use `C:` without overlapping.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much cleaned all his partitions. Thanks for the explanation. I'll let him know.